# Domain of existence for this ODE.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I think this is some pre-calculus concept that I've forgotten.

I am supposed to solve this initial value problem and determine how the interval in which the solution exists depends on $a$.

$$yy' + x = 0$$
$$y(0) = a > 0$$

I see it's a seperable equation.

$$\int ydy = \int-xdx$$

$$\frac{1}{2}y^2 = -\frac{1}{2}x^2 + c$$

Plugging in the initial value and solving for C:

$$\frac{1}{2}a^2 = -\frac{1}{2}0^2 + c$$

$$c = \frac{a^2}{2}$$

Plugging in the constant:

$$\frac{1}{2}y^2 = -\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{a^2}{2}$$

Solving for y:

$$y = ^+_-(a^2-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

I see that the squareroot must be $\ge 0$, so:

$$x^2 \le a^2$$

But our class notes say:

$$-a \le x \le a$$

And I don't understand how the last two lines are equivalent because I'm stupid.  Help?

Comment: Can you solve inequality $x^2 - a^2 \le 0$?

Comment: I did; $x^2 \le a^2$  Or further, I think, $x \le |a|$

Comment: No, no. I meant: $x^2\le a^2\Leftrightarrow x^2 - a^2\le 0\Leftrightarrow (x-a)(x+a)\le 0$ and use interval method for solving inequalities

Comment: Oh awesome, thank you.  That's exactly what I needed to see. :)

Comment: Note: you cannot compare $a$ and $-a$ in general case, but $-|a|\le |a|$ definitely. But in your case, $a>0$, and all is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2\leq a^2$
$\Rightarrow x^2-a^2 \leq 0$
$(x-a)(x+a)\leq 0$
$(x-a)(x- -a)\leq 0$
$\Rightarrow -a\leq x \leq a $

$x^2\geq a^2$
$\Rightarrow x^2-a^2 \geq 0$
$(x-a)(x+a)\geq 0$
$(x-a)(x- -a)\geq 0$
$\Rightarrow x \leq -a \cup x\geq a$

e.g take x=2

$x^2\leq 2^2$
$\Rightarrow x^2-2^2 \leq 0$
$(x-2)(x+2)\leq 0$
$(x-2)(x- -2)\leq 0$
$\Rightarrow -2\leq x \leq 2 $
Take any number between -2 and 2 and evaluate $x^2-a^2$,it will come out to be $\leq 0$

Answer (score 1):

That's almost done.
Since $x^2 \leq a^2$ taking square root we get $|x| \leq a$ which is same as $-a\leq x \leq a$.

Comment: Are you asking how $|x| \leq a$ is same as $- a \leq x \leq a$? That's straightforward.  Just think of |. | as distance from origin.